# How to hide the download button in an iframe src video?

Tags: javascript, iframe

in this code:

```
<iframe src="docs/videos/'+ nombreProyecto +'" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
```

I need to hide the download option. how do i do it?